# Is the limit inferior on a lower-, but not upper-bounded, sequence the infimum of all accumulation points?

Tags: sequences-and-series

On a lower- and upper bounded sequence, the limit inferior can be defined as the infimum of all accumulations points.

What if the sequence is only lower, but not upper bounded? Is it still defined as the infimum of all accumulation points?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sufficient to require that the sequence be bounded below; nothing in the argument below requires that the sequence be bounded above.

If $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence in $\Bbb R$ that is bounded below, by definition

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf_{m\ge n}x_m\;.$$

Let $L=\liminf_nx_n$, let $A$ be the set of accumulation points of the sequence, and let $u\in A$; then there is a subsequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converging to $u$. If $u<L$, there is a $k_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_{n_k}<\frac12(u+L)<L$ whenever $k\ge k_0$, and it follows that $\inf_{m\ge n}x_m<\frac12(u+L)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and hence that $L\le\frac12(u+L)<L$, which is absurd. Thus, $u\ge L$ for each $u\in A$.

Now let $\epsilon>0$; there is an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $|L-\inf_{m\ge n}x_m|<\frac{\epsilon}2$ for each $n\ge n_0$, and for each $n\ge n_0$ there is an $m_n\ge n$ such that $|x_{m_n}-\inf_{m\ge n}x_m|<\frac{\epsilon}2$ and hence

$$|L-x_{m_n}|\le|L-\inf_{m\ge n}x_m|+|x_{m_n}-\inf_{m\ge n}x_m|<\epsilon\;.$$

Thus, $L\in A$, and it follows immediately that $L=\inf A=\min A$.